# Is Android's JavaScript environment documented?

Tags: javascript, android

I'm looking for a JavaScript reference for Android's JavaScript environment, the objects provided by the browser, similar to the Mozilla Developer Center. Where is it?

I'm really looking for the browser documentation, specifically which XMLHttpRequest extensions have been implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing.  However, it is well-implemented, so the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) will serve you well.

**EDIT:** Regarding the browser's javascript environment, there exists no such documentation.

But see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768606/where-is-the-javascript-dom-api-documented) for related info about the DOM and its documentation or lack thereof.

Comment: I want to downvote your answer because it's so pathetic, but I have to accept it because it's true.

Comment: Thanks.  I strive for accuracy.