# Chrome DOM/JavaScript Reference

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

Is there a Chrome Javascript/DOM Reference page like the [*Mozilla Developer Network*](https://developer.mozilla.org/)?
which other page covers Chrome specific implementations of "The Standards"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768606/where-is-the-javascript-dom-api-documented/3768978#3768978

Comment: Combine the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) with [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing *Chrome* specific that I know of. There is [Webkit API documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/WebKitJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001232-SW1) but that is not very comprehensive and also just ends up pointing to MDN! If you see the *Using the Document Object Model From JavaScript → Other Resources* page it states:

> Mozilla [Gecko DOM Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) is one of the most comprehensive references for the JavaScript DOM

[WebPlatform.org](http://www.webplatform.org/) will eventually cover all browsers.

Also, I usually find that MDN highlights compatibility in other browsers anyway, for example Chrome is shown on the [DOM Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) page.

Comment: The problem is that Chrome implementation doesn't always comply with MDN and W3.org. In such cases, I end up reverse-engineering the docs.

Answer (score 2):

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-discuss/N56v_0tOVaM

Chrome uses V8 JavaScript Engine, it implements ECMAScript ECMA-262, http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.html

Check out these links for implementations and standards

Comment: Corrected second link:  http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm