# Chrome browser console javascript reference

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am looking for a reference table or a tutorial on the google browser console. I have started to do some front end javascript programming and using the console to log print so that I can explore the contents of my objects. But the log(printed items) are very confusing to me. I am having difficulty finding a resource on google to points to what ƒ (e), ƒ i(t) or  e {} or ƒ t(t,e,r) symbolizes when printed out on the google console. I can find out what scopes constructors, etc because I can google for them but I don't understand the rest. I found something similar on stack overflow at [Chrome DOM/JavaScript Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662958/chrome-dom-javascript-reference) but it doesn't have anything specific to address my queries as a beginner. I apologize if I ask my question wrongly because I dont know how to explain what these terms are. I would greatly appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction on where I can get these references or change my question so I can get the right answers.Below is a sample of what I mean, but I not limited to those few items I circled.

[image: sample console log]

Answer (score 1):

The slanted ƒ stands for "function" and denotes the data type of the variable/property that precedes it.

The ƒ can be followed by a function name (if it has one) and parameter names (if there are any defined in the function declaration).

So the following:

[image]

...means that `app` is a property with data type function: that function is called *i* 
and defines one parameter, called *t*.

You can for instance type the following object literal in the console:

```
{ fun: function test(num, arg) {} }
```

Then the console will show that value as follows:

[image]

The specification of the console API can be found [here](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/), but this leaves quite some room for implementation decisions. This is certainly true for the output format within the console. The [specification](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#optimally-useful-formatting) states:

> An object with **optimally useful formatting** is an implementation-specific, potentially-interactive representation of an object judged to be maximally useful and informative.

The [Chrome console API reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/api#dir) does not go into detail about the output format.